# Как убрать стандартное закругления кнопок в iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

Из названия заголовка уже можно понять что нужно. И всё таки, как убрать дефолтное закругление углов у инпутов на iOS?

[Картинка](http://joxi.ru/VrwJWkOt8jGKGA)

Comment: swift? xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение простое. В CSS пишем 2 строчки кода.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;

border-radius: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
  yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Куда это писать в js? А других методов нету?